# Retrieve by specific file name from document directory in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsfilemanager

Now i am retrieving file from document directory by specific name in iOS with following code.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToSearch = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError * error;

    arrayToSearch = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Manual.txt",documentsDirectory] error:&error];
```

I am sure i have the Manual.txt file in document directory.

However it doesn't show anything in tableView.

I also reload tableView.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Yes i am sure because i can get all lists of file from document directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:`. Read the name of the method. Read the description in the docs. The path you pass must reference a directory, not a file.

What you are trying to do doesn't make sense logically. If you know a specific file, then why search for it? Why create an array?

If you want to see if the file exists, use the `fileExistsAtPath:` method of `NSFileManager`.

If you just want the filename in the array then do:

```
NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Manual.txt"];
[arrayToSearch addObject:filename]; // since the array was pre-allocated
```

Please don't use `stringWithFormat` to create the filename. Use the proper `NSString` path methods like I did above.

Comment: Yes bro. i got it. But I am using with NSMutableArray. Can i use with @[filename]; bro?

Comment: Since you actually allocated the mutable earlier, you should do `[arrayToSearch addObject:filename];`. I'll update my answer.